# How to open pdf in my android app from file manager in android pie

Tags: android, android-intent

**Not working in Android-Pie only**

Not able to get file path from intent
result of intent.getData().getPath()   -> /2/19301

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
           </provider>

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type.endsWith("pdf")) {
            Uri file_uri = intent.getData();

            if (file_uri != null) {
                Log.d("file_path",""+file_uri.getPath());

                startActivity(new Intent(this, ReaderActivity.class).putExtra("file_path", file_uri.getPath()));
            } else {
                Log.e("Pdf_Viewer", "File Not Found");
            }
```

working on old devices
readstorage permission provided and granted
file provider already added

Comment: Well what is exactly the 'path' you get from that file manager? Tell the value of getData().toString() too  please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".PdfViewer" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
    <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

just update your menifest

Answer (score -1):

To get file path in Android 9(Pie) as follow

> in side onActivityResults - File originalFile = new File(FileUtils.getRealPath(getActivity(), uri));

Create new FileUtils as below

```
public class FileUtils {

public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
    String realPath;
    // SDK < API11
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        realPath = FileUtils.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        realPath = FileUtils.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
    }
    // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
    else {
        realPath = FileUtils.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
    }
    return realPath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = 0;
    String result = "";
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            // This is for checking Main Memory
            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                if (split.length > 1) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                } else {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                }
                // This is for checking SD Card
            } else {
                return "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
            }

        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            String fileName = getFilePath(context, uri);
            if (fileName != null) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
            }

            String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                id = id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                File file = new File(id);
                if (file.exists())
                    return id;
            }

            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

You have to add FileProvider inside Manifest.xml like below

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>.fileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Then Go to you java file and create below method and pass originalFile in this method

```
private void openPDF(File fileName) {
    try {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = fileName.getName().substring(fileName.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>.fileProvider", fileName);
                intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, type);
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileName), type);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No activity found to open this attachment.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will help you to open PDF file